# Java Google App Engine: Retrieve all entities sorted by property and inserted for later retrieval but keeping it's insert order

Tags: java, google-app-engine, queue, task, objectify

I'm using Java Google App Engine with Objectify3.0 (so some of the kinds may look different to standard JPO/JPA).

Anyways, I want to be able to retrieve all entities sorted by a property and insert it for later retrieval so that you get the results back in the sorted order that it was inserted.

Basically, this means I want a few things:

- Retrieve all entities (around 10,000)
  sorted by "name" in ascending order.The 30 seconds response limit will be hit if I try to get
  all of the entities in one go.
- Insert the order retrieved entities into another kind called:
  SortedByNameGame. This is the exact same kind as game (see below).
- Retrieve entities (with filters e.g. genre = action) from the SortedByNameGame kind but have them
  returned in the sorted ascending "name" property order in which
  entities were inserted.

My Game kind looks like this:

```
public class Game {
    @Id private Long id; //This is my key, auto generated by objectify  
    private String name;
    private String genre; 
    private Date releasedate;

    //ommitting getters and setters 
}
```

My SortedByNameGame kind looks like this:

```
public class SortedByNameGame {
    @Id private Long id; //This is my key, auto generated by objectify  
    private Long gameid; //This is the Long id of the Game kind shown above
    private String name;
    private String genre; 
    private Date releasedate;

    //ommitting getters and setters 
}
```

I've considered and tried a couple of approaches (all around recursive requests) but have been unsuccessful. For example:

- Cursors with tasks: I'm basically using this method: http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Cursors
- Cursors with RequestDispatcher.forward(request, response). Similar to http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Cursors
- Cursors with HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(/pathToThisServlet). Similar to http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Cursors
- Backends: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html. Looking into this since they dont have a 30 second reponse timelimit. However, I haven't got these working yet i.e. don't know how to access them via the browser. I'm getting a 404 Error Forbidden.

I suspect that recursive approach of requesting the same URL/Servlet aren't possible i.e. *"To prevent an app from causing an endless recursion of requests, a request handler is not allowed to fetch its own URL. It is still possible to cause an endless recursion with other means, so exercise caution if your app can be made to fetch requests for URLs supplied by the user."* (**source**: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview.html#Responses)

---

### My questions are

1. What am I doing wrong such that these recursive queue tasks aren't being created or recursive requests aren't working?
2. Alternatively, what other approaches exist to do what I want?

Comment: What's your ultimate goal here? I presume you want to retrieve the original ordering after it's changed? These approaches you've tried - are they for creating the dependent entites, or for querying them? User-facing, or on the task queue? What went wrong with your first 3 options?

Comment: I should have mentioned the final goal in the first post.

Basically, the end goal is to get a list of games filtered by releasedate ordered by ascending name.

For example a query like this:

filter("releasedate >=", 01/ 01/2011).filter("releasedate <=", 01/05/2011).order("releasedate").order("name);

The 1st order("releasedate") is a gae requirement since I'm using "releasedate" inequalities, I then apply the order("name").

But I noticed the returned results aren't ordered by ascending "name" but the results just keep the 1st order("releasedate")
I don't know why this is the case?

Comment: On the local dev datastore, when I step through code with breakpoints/eclipse debugger it creates the SortByNameGame kind and the entities for code I've stepped through. As soon as I remove all breakpoints and let it run on it ceases to create an more entities. 

It seems like my recursion is working when I step though. Not sure if I'm getting the recursive exit clause right. I'll have to experiement with a smaller set maybe 10 or 15 entities to check what's happenning. The funny thing is that I'm using task queues fine but creating recursive tasks using the same serlvet becauase the issue.

Comment: After testing with the small 10 to 15 entities I discovered that it was my code causing the recursion to not exit properly & not store the entities.

Comment: The most disappointing thing is that even after I fixed it and was able to create the SortedByNameGame kind. Running a query like `filter("releasedate >=", 01/ 01/2011).filter("releasedate <=", 01/05/2011)` still causes the results to be ordered by asc releasedate. It seems to override the insert order of ascending name (which I can clearly see in the datastore tab of admin portal that rows are order by asc name). Why does my filter cause filter("releasedate >=", 01/ 01/2011).filter("releasedate <=", 01/05/2011) the returned results to be reordered when I haven't told it to be reordered :(

Comment: @Stewie Results are ordered first by any inequality properties, then any explicit sort orders, then by key. How big is this list of results? How often will you refer to it with a given date threshold?

Comment: Stewie, did you find solution to your problem ?

Comment: I never did find my solution and gave up on this (very simple) feature unfortunately. I would more examples in the documentation starting from simple to complex, illustrating how GAE filtering and sorting works, especially when there are implicit (which I dont understand why they are required when it actually causes confusion) sorts as mentioned by Nick.